# Vertical spacing for own list of equation

Tags: xetex, equations, lists, koma-script, scrbook

I added a list of equation to my bachelor thesis. For this I used the code

The corresponding list of equation look like this, I want to change the space between the two equations :
[image]

I now want to change the vertical spaces between the entries but I only found the options to adjust the horizontal spaces of the loe. It should look like my list of figure with a different vertical spacing :[image]

The mwe for the list of equation looks like this :

```
\documentclass[%
    a4paper,            % Papierformat
    oneside,            % einseitiger Druck
    %twoside,           % zweiseitiger Druck
    12pt,               % Schriftgröße
    onecolumn,          % einspaltiger Text
    %twocolumn,         % zweispaltiger Text
    openright,          % Kapitel dürfen nur auf einer rechten Seite beginnen
    openany,            % Kapitel dürfen rechts oder links beginnen
    parskip=half,       % eine halbe Zeile Abstand zw. Absätzen
    headsepline,        % Kopfzeilenlinie
    footsepline,        % Fußzeilenlinie
    bibliography=totoc, % Bibliographie im Inhaltsverzeichnis
    %idxtotoc           % Index im Inhaltsverzeichnis
    ]{scrbook}

\usepackage{ifxetex}

\ifxetex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}
\else
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\fi


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tocbibind}



    \DeclareNewTOC[%
    indent=0em,% kein Einzug im Verzeichnis
    hang=4em,% Einzug für den Text im Verzeichnis
    type=equation,
    ]{loe}

    \AtBeginDocument{%
        \newcaptionname{ngerman}\equationname{Formel}%
        \newcaptionname{ngerman}\listequationname{Formelverzeichnis}%
    }

    % Dafür sorgen, dass Einträge immer dann erzeugt werden können, wenn auch Tags
    % gesetzt werden:
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand*{\@currentenftry}{}
    % Zwei amsmath-Anweisungen ändern:
    \g@addto@macro\make@display@tag{\set@currententry}%
    \def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}%
        \set@currententry}
    \newcommand*{\set@currententry}{%
        \typeout{set current entry}%
        \ifx\@currententry\@empty\else
        \addcontentsline{loe}{equation}{\protect\numberline{\@currentlabel}%
            \@currententry}%
        \global\let\@currententry\@empty
        \fi
    }
    % Neue Benutzeranweisung
    \newcommand*{\equationentry}[1]{%
        \gdef\@currententry{#1}%
    }
    \makeatother



\begin{document}


\begin{equation}\label{eq.dsakf} \equationentry{Delta der SAKF}
    \dot{R}_M(k) = \dfrac{\sum_{m =-M}^{M} mR(k+m) }{\sum_{m=-M}^{M}m^2}
\end{equation}


\begin{equation} \label{eq.sigma_level} \equationentry{Absoluter Mittelwert (MAD) der Koeffizienten}
\sigma_j = MAD_j/0,6745 
\end{equation}



\listofequations

\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Posting a header file cannot replace a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Please remove all not needed code from your question and replace it by a MWE starting with `\documentclass` adding only those packages and preamble codes you need to reproduce the problem and a complete but minimal body from `\begin{document}` to `\end{document}`, e.g., using dummy text and images from [`mwe`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mwe).

Comment: Off-topic: I would recommend to replace obsolete `scrpage2` by almost compatible `scrlayer-scrpage`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use package `tocbibind` with KOMA-Script classes. It is responsible for using the increased paragraph skip also for the list of figure. That should not be done.

```
\documentclass[%
    a4paper,            % Papierformat
    oneside,            % einseitiger Druck
    %twoside,           % zweiseitiger Druck
    12pt,               % Schriftgröße
    onecolumn,          % einspaltiger Text
    %twocolumn,         % zweispaltiger Text
    %openright,          % Kapitel dürfen nur auf einer rechten Seite beginnen
    openany,            % Kapitel dürfen rechts oder links beginnen
    parskip=half,       % eine halbe Zeile Abstand zw. Absätzen
    headsepline,        % Kopfzeilenlinie
    footsepline,        % Fußzeilenlinie
    listof=totoc,       % Gleitumgebungsverzeichnisse im Inhaltsverzeichnis
    bibliography=totoc, % Bibliographie im Inhaltsverzeichnis
    %index=totoc           % Index im Inhaltsverzeichnis
    ]{scrbook}

\usepackage{ifxetex}

\ifxetex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}
\else
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\fi

\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{tocbibind}

\DeclareNewTOC[%
  indent=0em,% kein Einzug im Verzeichnis
  hang=4em,% Einzug für den Text im Verzeichnis
  type=equation,
]{loe}

\newcaptionname{ngerman}\equationname{Formel}%
\newcaptionname{ngerman}\listequationname{Formelverzeichnis}%

% Dafür sorgen, dass Einträge immer dann erzeugt werden können, wenn auch Tags
% gesetzt werden:
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\@currentenftry}{}
% Zwei amsmath-Anweisungen ändern:
\g@addto@macro\make@display@tag{\set@currententry}%
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}%
    \set@currententry}
\newcommand*{\set@currententry}{%
    \typeout{set current entry}%
    \ifx\@currententry\@empty\else
    \addcontentsline{loe}{equation}{\protect\numberline{\@currentlabel}%
        \@currententry}%
    \global\let\@currententry\@empty
    \fi
}
% Neue Benutzeranweisung
\newcommand*{\equationentry}[1]{%
    \gdef\@currententry{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq.dsakf} \equationentry{Delta der SAKF}
    \dot{R}_M(k) = \dfrac{\sum_{m =-M}^{M} mR(k+m) }{\sum_{m=-M}^{M}m^2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation} \label{eq.sigma_level} \equationentry{Absoluter Mittelwert (MAD) der Koeffizienten}
\sigma_j = MAD_j/0,6745 
\end{equation}

\captionof{figure}{Allgemeine Verarbeitungskette für ein SAD}
\captionof{figure}{Mithörschwellen für Schmalbandrauschen}

\listofequations
\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

results in:

[image: Formelverzeichnis]
[image: Abbildungsverzeichnis]

If you really want the ugly spaces in the tocs, you can use enforce it using `\BeforeStartingTOC{\KOMAoptions{parskip=half}\selectfont}` in the document preamble. This would result in:

[image: Formelverzeichnis with parskip]
[image: Formelverzeichnis with parskip]

Please note also my additional changes of the `scrbook` options and the removing of the not needed `\AtBeginDocument`.

Additionally note: If you are not using a very old KOMA-Script version, you should replace

```
\DeclareNewTOC[%
  indent=0em,% kein Einzug im Verzeichnis
  hang=4em,% Einzug für den Text im Verzeichnis
  type=equation,
]{loe}
```

by

```
\DeclareNewTOC[%
  tocentryindent=0em,% kein Einzug im Verzeichnis
  tocentrynumwidth=4em,% Einzug für den Text im Verzeichnis
  type=equation,
]{loe}
```

to avoid the warnings:

> ```
> Package tocbasic Warning: deprecated option `indent'.
> (tocbasic)                You should replace option `indent' by option
> (tocbasic)                `tocentryindent' on input line 38.
>
>
> Package tocbasic Warning: deprecated option `hang'.
> (tocbasic)                You should replace option `hang' by option
> (tocbasic)                `tocentrynumwidth' on input line 38.
> ```

Comment: @skop ??? I've shown both, with and without the extra vertical space!